# DNF to CNF of a simple expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I have a formula like this:
$$\bigvee_{\substack{i \in [1,...,m] \\ j \in [1,...,m]}} x_{i} \wedge x_{j}$$
What is the equivalent formula in CNF (conjunctive normal form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

First see how this goes for a simple concrete example, and then try and make out the general pattern from that.

So, for a simple example, suppose $m=2$. So that means that you are dealing with the following expression:

$(x_1 \land x_1) \lor (x_1 \land x_2) \lor (x_2 \land x_1) \lor (x_2 \land x_2)$

Now, note that by Idempotence, $(x_1 \land x_1)$ is equivalent to just $x_1$.

Also, by Absorption, you have that $x_1 \lor (x_1 \lor x_2)$ is equivalent to just $x_1$.

So, the whole expression is equivalent to simply $x_1 \lor x_2$ ... which is in CNF.

Now, what do you think happens if we do this for any $m$ in general?